# Ansible copy fails: template error

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Using a local vagrant VM, I want to deploy a .war-file. Running the following simple ansible-playbook, I got stuck. The ansible-master-playbook is included in the Vagrantfile and run within the 'vagrant provision' process. Long story short: the playbook below is run.

```
---
  - copy: src={{ ci files }}/app.war dest=/path/to/webapps/app.war
  [...]
```

The variable 'files' is inherited from the master-playbook.

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: vagrant
  vars:
    ci_files: /local-user/ci
```

This is the error:

```
fatal: [default] => Failed to template src={{ files }}/opencms.war dest=/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ mode=0755: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'files'
```

---

Found the answer while writing this question and will provide the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

Ansible **variables** may **not** contain **spaces**. Fixing the reference solved the issue:

```
- copy: src={{ ci_files }}/app.war dest=/path/to/webapps/app.war
```

Let's understand what Ansible did:

It tried to parse the string `{{ ci files }}`. However the second whitespace indicated that the variable's end was reached. As a result Ansible expects the next section of characters (token) to be the closing parentheses, but gets `files`. The closing parentheses are the token for `end of print statement`.

Comment: Why would you ever think a variable name can contain spaces?

Comment: Asked myself that question a few days ago.